# Short Fibonacci Heap

Tags: data-structures, heaps, priority-queues

Is it possible to create a Fibonacci Heap that has exactly 5 nodes: one root node and 4 children of that root?. If yes please explain the sequence of operations to do so. If it is not possible then why?

I faced this question in an interview but couldn't answer it. Hopefully can learn it from here.

Comment: Welcome to Computer Science! The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Comment: Choose and cite a definition of *Fibonacci Heap*, and start arguing. (There are data structures where certain configurations can not be reached by additions to *empty*, only: you may need deletions, too.)

Comment: @greybeard Hi, for me the definition is Fibonacci Heap is a collection of trees with min-heap or max-heap property. In Fibonacci Heap, trees can can have any shape even all trees can be single nodes .

Comment: I think I see where your problem started. I am not happy with Fredman&Tarjan's `We impose no explicit constraints on the number or structure of the trees`, there ***are*** `constraints [implied by] the way the trees are manipulated.`

Answer (score 1):

Corollary 1 in [Fredman & Tarjan's paper](http://bioinfo.ict.ac.cn/~dbu/AlgorithmCourses/Lectures/Fibonacci-Heap-Tarjan.pdf) states:

> A node of rank $k$ in an F-heap has at least $F_{k+2} \ge \phi^k$ descendants,
>   including itself; where $F_k$ is the $k$th Fibonacci number ($F_0 = 0$, $F_1 = 1$, $F_k = F_{k-2} + F_{k-1}$ for $k \ge 2$), and $\phi = (1 + \sqrt{5})/2$ is the golden ratio.

Any node of rank 4 must have at least $F_{4+2} = 8$ descendants including itself, but the root node in the example has only 5. Therefore it could not have been created using Fibonacci heap operations.